# Excel 2016 cannot access DDE server

Tags: excel, dde

I'm using Excel 2016 to access a DDE server (Rockwell Software's RSLinx Classic.) The DDE server is working correctly/can be accessed from other applications. The problem is trying to access it from Excel.

This is what is in my cell: =RSLinx|PS9TOPIC1!'N7:0'

The PS9TPIC1 topic is set up (and works) in RSLinx. RSLinx is up and running. But I get:

> Remote data not accessible... Start application RSLINX.EXE?

Clicking Yes gets:

> Cannot run 'RSLINX.EXE'. The program or one of its components is missing or corrupted

The program runs fine. I have ensured that RSLinx.exe is on the PATH (Double-checked the PATH for the running Excel using Task Manager.) It doesn't matter whether I have RSLinx running before starting Excel or have Excel try to launch it.

No, the option to "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange" is *not* checked for this document.

I tried running both RSLinx and Excel as "Administrator" with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Bringing up the help for data connections shows this:
Note: In an earlier version of Excel, you might have used Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) in combination with the Step-by-Step Mail Merge Wizard in Word. Excel no longer supports DDE. If you'd like us to consider this feature for the next version of Excel, drop us a comment in the Excel Suggestion Box.

Try using an older Excel license.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i already solved it. Just go to your project in the kepserver, open  properties, and make sure enable the DDE conection to your server... Just that in my case. Good luck..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHkUJ.png)